# Using an array as a global

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, multidimensional-array

I know declaring global is not a thing for c# . And i have this code for a multi dimensional array where  i  want user to input the no of rows and then no of cols for each row.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Multidimensional_Array
{

class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ENter the no of rows ");
            int rows=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

           for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Enter no of columns for "+i+" row");
                   var columns  = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                int [,] multiDynamic=new int[rows,columns];
                Console.WriteLine("enter " +i+ " row elements");
                for(int j=0;j<columns;j++)
                {
                    multiDynamic[i,j]=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }


            }
            Console.WriteLine("The array elements are ");


    }
}
```

Now while trying writing code for displaying array i found that scope of array `multiDynamic` will remain inside the for loop .Is there any way to access this array ?

**Update**   --the `columns` array also need to be accessed while displaying array in the end . Please post solution for this too .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** updated based on comment.

Use Jagged array.

```
     int [][] multiDynamic=new int[rows][];

   for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter no of columns for "+i+" row");
           var columns  = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        multiDynamic[i] = new int[columns];
        Console.WriteLine("enter " +i+ " row elements");
        for(int j=0;j<columns;j++)
        {
            multiDynamic[i][j]=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }


    }
    Console.WriteLine("The array elements are ");
```

You can access inner Array (columns) as below

```
     foreach(var innerArray in multiDynamic)
     {
             foreach(var item in innerArray)
             {
               Console.WriteLine(item);
             }
             Console.WriteLine();
     }
```

Comment: Cant do that as the colums have to from the user for each row !!

Comment: in that case you have to use [jagged arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx). Multi dimension arrays have fixed length

Comment: But columns array is also out of scope !!

Answer (score 1):

Declare the array outside the loop.

```
int [,] multiDynamic = null;
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Enter no of columns for "+i+" row");
            var columns  = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
             multiDynamic=new int[rows,columns];
            Console.WriteLine("enter " +i+ " row elements");
            for(int j=0;j<columns;j++)
            {
                multiDynamic[i,j]=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }


        }
```

Comment: multiDynamic is declared twice. It will not compile

Answer (score 1):

declare it outside the first loop.

Answer (score -1):

declare it at outer scrope:

```
int rows=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int [,] multiDynamic=new int[rows,columns];
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
{

    Console.WriteLine("Enter no of columns for "+i+" row");
       var columns  = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("enter " +i+ " row elements");
    for(int j=0;j<columns;j++)
    {
        multiDynamic[i,j]=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }


}
Console.WriteLine("The array elements are ");
```